# Accepting 0-confirmation transactions and detecting double-spends with open source solution

Tags: transactions

I would like to accept 0-confirmation bitcoin for very small amounts. I am happy to accept zero-confirmation spends and am aware of the risks. However, the tool needs the ability to "flag" the accepted transaction/s if a double-spend is detected. I can then decide what action to take.

I do not want to use a centralized third-party tool. I would like to use something locally on the server. It would simply display pre-generated public addresses. No need for private keys and/or seeds to be on the server.

Does such a tool exist?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried to clarify a title bit. Hopefully it is ok.

Comment: I would imagine you need to interact directly with bitcoind, but there are some wrappers.

Comment: Here is one: https://github.com/snitko/straight-server - you can try to fish out Bitcond wrappers for your favorite programming language on Github search. EDIT: Straight uses blockchain.info instead of Bitcoin network, so it is out of the question

Answer (score 1):

You should not interact with bitcoind, because it (current versions at least) filteres double-spend transactions

You should have your own network-sniffer solutution - the program which connects to the network nodes (as many as possible) and listens for **all** transactions, checking do they have conflicts with particular ones.

(How much would you pay for such program? Just interesting :) )

This is also not 100% safe solution - a miner can place double-spending transaction in block and mine it himself. Look here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=327767.0

Comment: You can send a question to an owner of http://respends.thinlink.com/ Hope it helps

Comment: Isn't this: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/32636/14319 a way to detect double-spending through bitcoind?

Answer (score 0):

Yes bitcoind filters double-spends. I am not aware of anything that can listen and detect double-spends. I too would be interested in this. I would imagine that a simple tool would be needed which just detects double-spends. You could then do as you wish with the tx ID and notify an existing payment application.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Bitcoin XT](https://github.com/bitcoinxt/bitcoinxt/releases) which is an early release version of functions that are proposed for Bitcoin Core.  It relays double spends, and notifies the wallet of double-spend attempts that affect it.

You can hook up your own code to be run immediately when a double-spend is detected, using the -respendnotify option.