# Why are double-spends bad?

Tags: bitcoind, doublespend

In the answer to [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30750/accepting-0-confirmation-transactions-and-detecting-double-spends-with-open-sour) it is stated the bitcoind filters doublespends. What is the reasoning behind this?