# JSON-RPC to detect double-spent TXs

Tags: json-rpc, doublespend

How can I be positive that one of the incoming payments to my bitcoin-core was double-spent after it was confirmed once by the network, through the JSON-RPC interface?

Related questions:

- [How do I detect a double-spend?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13370/how-do-i-detect-a-double-spend)
- [Accepting 0-confirmation transactions and detecting double-spends with open source solution](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30750/accepting-0-confirmation-transactions-and-detecting-double-spends-with-open-sour)
- https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=327767.0 (GHash.IO and double-spending against BetCoin Dice)

Answer (score 2):

If your node received the original spend, the [`listunspent` RPC](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#listunspent) will display the transaction with "-1" confirmations, as will any other RPCs that would normally list the transaction.  The source code [calls this conflicted:](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/b7fe9cd04cd2756b1ce40b668d25a130441ba847/src/wallet.h#L539) "not in the mempool and not in the block chain."  This feature was first included in [0.9.0](https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.9.0).

If your node never received the original spend (perhaps because it was offline at the time) or the now-stale block that contained it, it doesn't have any way to know about that original spend, so there's no information you can get from an RPC.

Comment: Thanks David! Now I'm really concerned about this: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/730/what-does-the-bitcoin-client-do-when-it-receives-conflicting-transactions I wish I could find an update on that answer

Comment: AFAIR `listunspent` doesn't return txs that have < 0 confirmations. `listsinceblock` will not show them either but you can use `listtransactions` instead which does.